# How to use geoNear with the current PHP MongoDB Driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I'm currently working with the current [PHP MongoDB\Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) .

I need to use an `geoNear` query to fetch points from my current location. The required `2dsphere index` is already set, the query works in the console and delivers multiple results:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear: 'pois', near: [ 52.264633, 6.12485 ], spherical: true, maxDistance: 1000, distanceField: 'distance'})
```

Since the previous methods are deprecated, I can't use the old `aggregate` functions.

I'm now trying to find the right way to build the query I need with the current `Query` or `Command` classes.

What I've tried is the following:

```
$query = array(
    'geoNear' => 'pois',
    "near" => array(
        52.264633,
        6.12485
    ),
    "spherical" => true,
    "maxDistance" => 1000,
    "distanceField" => "distance"
);
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command($query);
$returnCursor = $this->conn->executeCommand("database.pois", $cmd);
$arrReturn = $returnCursor->toArray();
return $arrReturn;
```

If I use this, I will return this Runtime Error:

```
"exception": [
    {
      "type": "MongoDB\\Driver\\Exception\\RuntimeException",
      "code": 18,
      "message": "Failed to decode document from the server."
    } 
]"
```

I couldn't find a solution for my case and also I couldn't find more information to this error.

If I change the `Command` up to a `Query`, the execution doesn't fail, but there are no results.

My mongodb is on the version 3.2, my PHP version is PHP Version 7.0.16-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 and the mongodb Exension is version 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregate in the following way with new driver.

```
$pipeline = array(array(
    '$geoNear'=> array(
    'near' => array(
        52.264633,
        6.12485
    ),
    'spherical' => true,
    'maxDistance' => 1000,
    'distanceField' => "distance"
)));

$cmd = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'pois', 
    'pipeline' => $pipeline
]);

$returnCursor = $this->conn->executeCommand("database", $cmd);
$arrReturn = $returnCursor->toArray();
```

Comment: Is there any source where you've found this? I couldn't find something about this. But it works, thanks.

Comment: Well, I completely overlooked this, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a [Library from Mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/) that expands the default functionality of the driver to make it a little more user friendly

but as its not built into the php website its easy to miss

[MongoDB\Collection::aggregate($pipeline, $options)](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-aggregate/)

where

```
$pipeline = array(array(
    '$geoNear'=> array(
        'near' => array(
            52.264633,
            6.12485
         ),
        'spherical' => true,
        'maxDistance' => 1000,
        'distanceField' => "distance"
    )
));
```